# jQuery Mobile popup blurred

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, jquery-mobile, safari

I get trouble with popups on jQuery mobile while using my form on iPad (Safari).

Popups on my page are totaly blurred, when I resize or use my virtuel keyboard popups go back to normal.

my pop up :

```
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupConjoint" data-dom-cache="true"  data-theme="a" data-position-to="window">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="g" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right radius">Close</a>

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">

        <div id="popup_Conj_div1">
             <div>

        </div>
            <div id="popup_Conj_div2" style="display:none; text-align : center;" >
            </div> 

            <div id="popup_Conj_div3" style="display:none;">
            </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

my popup call :

```
               $('#popupEnfant').popup();
    $('#popup_Enf_div1').show();
    $('#popup_Enf_div2').hide();
    $('#popup_Enf_div3').hide();    
            $( "#detailassureEnfant" ).popup("open");
```

[see the result](http://postimg.org/image/m915lk8jl/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried to add this to css?

```
.ui-popup { -webkit-transform:translateZ(0) }
```

Someone mentioning similar problem in the follwoing forum

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/1-2-popup-picture-gets-blurry-on-my-android-4-0-phone-also-on-the-demo-page

Answer (score 0):

mara-mfa's answer didn't help me with this same issue.

Solved it by adding:

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
-webkit-transform: inherit !important;
-moz-transform: inherit !important;
-o-transform: inherit !important;
transform: inherit !important;
}
```

I am using ui-bootstrap so maybe this is why I needed another solution..